# What is the correct method to limit information that a user can retrieve within a PHP application accessing MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am in the process of creating an online interface that connects to our internal order database with the idea that eventually customers will be able to view their orders that we have in the system etc.

I have a basic interface set up and working, i.e. I can search for orders by reference in our order database and they are returned in a table etc. The basics are there but I cannot grasp the idea of how I am meant to limit this per user, so User A cannot search for orders that User B has placed.

I'll explain our database in a *very* simple form:

We have an `orders` table that contains things like `order_number`, `creation_date`, `customer_number` etc.

Should I now create an `online_users` table, and link each user to the corresponding `customer_number` in the `orders` table, or is there a *better* way to do this? Should I just add columns `online_user` and `online_pass` to our `customers` table and only allow a single user and password for each customer account?

Then we get to the actual online login, I can create a form that connects and identifies users and allows them to login, that part is ok, but how do I somehow store what customer account they are from during the login, and how can I then use this in the SQL queries later on? I was thinking I could just add a cookie with whatever customer account is returned during login, but surely that isn't safe and users can just edit it to another customer account.

**Edit:** What I am asking here is how do I limit SQL results to just the company that the user is associated with?

```
$q = "SELECT * 
      FROM orders
      WHERE customer_number = SOMETHING";
```

*SOMETHING* needs to be the customer number that the user is linked to, this could be returned in the login phase but how do I store this to be used in the SQL queries?

Comment: Do you know about [ACL conception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) ?

Comment: You need to implement an access control list system.  This is why a lot of times it is easier to use a framework or even a full CMS that has these things implemented and you can just add the parts you need. Any of the major CMSes will have extensions that manage this kind of thing.

Comment: @MichaelLivach Yes as I explained in the question I plan to create users etc. however the question was more aimed at once the user has logged in and a customer number has been returned in the login query how do I then store this for use in future SQL queries? I've updated the question if it was unclear.

Comment: @user2656114. you may put customer id in session. Session data stores on server side, client receives only session cookie. Session storage may be different: files (by default), database etc, see [session.save-handler](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-handler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could indeed make a table which holds customer data that's linked via the customer_number.

EDIT : And optionally create a permissions table where you would assign certain users to certain groups.

As for the login information use, you can work with sessions.

Check out these links :

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Hope I helped you.

Comment: Thanks. I have read the links and understand a bit but would it be possible please to explain how I should/would use these in this scenario?

Comment: Well, when you authenticated a user you could store these in a session. For example. :

session_start(); //needed at the start of every script that uses it)

$_SESSION['user'] = $userInfoFromDatabase;

On other pages you could then retrieve this info like :

session_start();

$user = $_SESSION['user'];